# How add elements to an existing map firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i am doing some work with flutter and firebase, so i can't figure out how add new elements to an existing document who has an existing map with some created fields so.. the map for example is this

```
'Users':{uid0:{'Name':{'userName0'},uid1:{'Name':{'userName1'}}
```

An this is my actual code.

```
Firestore.instance.collection('on_going_matches').where('userSlot',isGreaterThan: 0).snapshots().listen(
          (data) => {
              Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
                await transaction.update(Firestore.instance.collection("on_going_matches").document(data.documents[0].documentID), {
                  'users': {uid:{'Name':name}},
                  'userSlot': data.documents[0]['userSlot'] - 1
                }
                );
              })
              });
```

I have another question too, what i can do when "where" condition `"where('userSlot',isGreaterThan: 0)"` is not found, how i can use this like an if/else statement so, if Firestore query is not found, do a thing.

Comment: to update an existing document: myDocument.setData(myMap, merge: true);

Comment: Yeah, thanks, i was trying to do this with transactions... but i realized that i can't

Comment: Nice to hear that. Please, upvote my awnser :)

Answer (score 4):

To update an existing document: `myDocument.setData(myMap, merge: true);`